# Custom input reader in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-streaming

I am new to Spark and would like to load page records from a Wikipedia dump into an RDD.

I tried using a record reader provided in hadoop streaming but can't figure out how to use it. Could anyone help me make the following code create a nice RDD with page records?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object WikiTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // configuration
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[4]")
      .setAppName("WikiDumpTest")

    val jobConf = new JobConf()
    jobConf.set("input", "enwikisource-20140906-pages-articles-multistream.xml")
    jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.class", "org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader")
    jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.begin", "<page>")
    jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.end", "</page>")
      
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  
    // read data
    val wikiData = sparkContext.hadoopRDD(
        jobConf, 
        classOf[StreamXmlRecordReader],
        classOf[Text], 
        classOf[Text])

    // count rows
    println(wikiData.count)
  }
}
```

It seems Spark refuses to use StreamXmlRecordReader. I get the following error:

> [error]  found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader (classOf[org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader])
>
> [error] required: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[?,?]]
>
> [error]         classOf[StreamXmlRecordReader]

If I ignore Eclispse's warning and launch the prgramm anyway I hit a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `classOf[org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamInputFormat]` instead of `classOf[StreamXmlRecordReader]`.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is because you want to run your class `WikiTest` but it does not exist as it cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

You're having the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` because you are trying to use an external dependency in spark (`StreamXmlRecordReader`). You have to create a fat jar, and deploy it in Spark.

This is a good example on how to create this type of jar: [gradle fat jar tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/)

Also you can have a look here if you have problems parsing the XML file:
[parsing tutorial](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201411.mbox/%3CCAKn3j0v-6-K7qRRJMraqoV79zvYOWnSijNYj8bj5o+6UpLJfTw@mail.gmail.com%3E)